# How to get the path of a file that defines a class, in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

In a Flutter app, I have a dart file located at `FlutterTest\sandbox\lib\my_widget\my_widget.dart`, containing a class called `MyWidget`.

Can I, from this class, get the location of the file where it is defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. Flutter disable `dart:mirror` so you can't use reflection.

Comment: Do you know why it's disabled?

Comment: To reduce binary size. Generally speaking in dart, we use code generation instead of reflection.

Comment: Dart for Flutter is AoT compiled, this means in the released app, there won't be `my_widget.dart` file

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in another answer/comments, that information is stripped out at runtime.

<s>However, if you're motivated enough you could write a [pub transformer](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/assets-and-transformers) that uses regex to pick up a special symbol you define and exchange it for the file path at runtime.</s> Edit: transformers aren't supported in flutter.

You may be able to do this with the [Build package & tooling](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/build) introduced in Dart 2, but you'll have to make sure you're using a version of flutter that uses dart 2 (the beta branch/channel probably doesn't yet, the dev may or may not, but master does).

Comment: "pub transformers" are only for Dart 1 and only for web projects. I think you bretter remove that part and replace it with a reference to the build package.

Comment: Ah didn't realize you couldn't use them in flutter.

Comment: I am not that motivated. I will consider that, in practice, you can't.